# Zend Framework retrieving value from DB

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Session\Container;
```

Hi i am new to ZF2 and i  couldn't able to echo it.

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
$row = $rowset->current();
echo $row->name;
```

Comment: What is the content of var_dump($row) ?

Comment: Do you have "name" field in database?

Comment: yeah there is name field....

Comment: Have you tried to print $row?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

echo $row['name'];

This works from me.